# cannot run .jlnp jenkins agent on OpenJDK

Tags: java, jenkins

I downloaded the jenkins client agent, `.jlnp` file but it cannot run on `OpenJDK`.
Java JRE is now allowed to be installed in the machine.

what is the alternative to run jenkins client?

Comment: Have your read the documentation? any issues with it?

Comment: i am not sure if it is limitation. For now, I use .bat method and run the CLI command instead of executing .jlnp file.